# Laravel 5.7 changing default auth table

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

i'm a real laravel noob as i was obliged to work with it for my uni project, i've been trying for 5 hours now to make authentification work on my project with no avail, i've been trying to switch the default auth table from users with utilisateurs (my custom db table), it has all prerequisites yet whenever i click on the login button it just refreshes the login page, a side note i'm not trying to use register form as in the context of my project, only a utilisateur is able to add another utilisateur, my custom db table "utilisateur" has the following rows (idutilisateur,pseudo,mdp,telephone,usertype,bloque,remember_token,created_at,updated_at)

this is my LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/utilisateurs';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
   {
       $credentials = $request->only('pseudo', 'mdp');

       if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
           // Authentication passed...
           return redirect()->intended('utilisateurs');
       }
   }
}
```

This is login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="text" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Pseudo') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="pseudo" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('pseudo') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="pseudo" value="{{ old('pseudo') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('pseudo'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('pseudo') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Mot de passe') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="mdp" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('mdp') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="mdp" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('mdp'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('mdp') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

this is auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'utilisateurs',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'utilisateurs',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'utilisateurs' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Utilisateur::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'utilisateurs' => [
            'provider' => 'utilisateurs',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

I really hope you people would help me i'll be really grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this tutorial - https://www.5balloons.info/changing-authentication-table-laravel/

Answer (score 1):

You must create a new Model to your User that extends `Authenticatable`, like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class CustomUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'customusers';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','username','email', 'passcode','active'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'passcode', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
      return $this->passcode;
    }
}
```

And change in your app where you use User class to your CustomUser class. Check this tutorial:
https://www.5balloons.info/changing-authentication-table-laravel/

If you don't want to have all this work, you could simply define in the User class `protected $table = 'yourcustomuserstable'`and adapt it to your table but I think it would get really weird.

Comment: Still just refreshes the login page and nothing happens, no errors or messages